# how to unsubscribe nested observable | Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

Depending on the URL param, i am subscribing to an observable (_getData).

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._subscription.add(
      this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((params) => { this._getData(params.get('name')).subscribe() })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Now every time the param changes, I am subscribing to a new observable (_getData).. **So how do i unsubscribe the previous observable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switchMap` to manage your subscriptions for you. In this case, every time there are new params, the old `this._getData` is unsubscribed and a new `this._getData` is subscribed for you.

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
    switchMap(params => this._getData(params.get('name')))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mergeMap` to flatten the inner observable which is the `this._getData()`

In the code below, I didn't subscribe to your second observable and instead used mergeMap. I did this so that there is only 1 child subscription and will be unsubscribed by the parent `this._subscription` when you unsubscribe from it.

```
this._subscription.add(
  this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
    mergeMap((params) => {
      return this._getData(params.get('name'))
    })
  ).subscribe()
);
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't care for the `route.queryParamMap` afterwards you might want to use `switchMap` instead.

Comment: This doesnt help..  I dont want to unsubscribe `this.route.queryParamMap` but what i want is to unsubscribe `_getData()` everytime the param value changes